# SQLAlchemy : random Unique integer?

Tags: python, random, sqlalchemy, unique, identifier

I can do this to set column type to be unique string :

```
    uuid = Column(String,  default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), unique=True)
```

but I want to generate **random-unique-integer**, not random-unique-string.

any idea how to do that ?

---

uuid.uuid4().int

thanks. If I can respecify :) is there a way to fit it into DB Integer type.

Comment: Access it's int-attribute: ```uuid.uuid4().int``` as described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html).

Comment: Or just use a sequence, which will give you unique integers that just happen to be ordered but who's to say they weren't generated randomly and you were just lucky?

Comment: @larsks Try to explain this to some safety-consultant when checking your code :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
from random import randint 

def random_integer():
    min_ = 100
    max_ = 1000000000
    rand = randint(min_, max_)

    # possibility of same random number is very low.
    # but if you want to make sure, here you can check id exists in database.
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    db_session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=your_db_engine)
    db_session = db_session_maker()
    while db_session.query(Table).filter(uuid == rand).limit(1).first() is not None:
        rand = randint(min_, max_)

    return rand

class Table(Base):
    uuid = Column(String,  default=random_integer, unique=True)
```

Comment: Why make the column a String and not an integer?

Comment: The question clearly states OP wants a INTEGER type, so this answer doesn't work. See my answer for an INTEGER type.

Answer (score 0):

The INTEGER type in DB is 4 bytes (32 bits).

The `uuid.uuid4().int` generate a 128 bits integer.

So just ignore most of the bits (with bitwise shift operator) :

```py
uuid = Column(Integer,  default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().int >> (128 - 32), unique=True)
```